# powercfg won't honor -requestsoverride

Tags: windows-10, powercfg

Currently I have two drivers that is preventing my Windows 10 from sleeping (running Command Prompt as administrator):

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] USB Audio Device (USB\VID_1395&PID_005E&MI_00\6&61162f7&0&0000)
An audio stream is currently in use.
[DRIVER] Legacy Kernel Caller

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None.
```

So I added them via the `-requestsoverride` command like

```
powercfg -requestsoverride Driver "Legacy Kernel Caller" System
```

Then I can see the two drivers made it on the override list:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -requestsoverride
[SERVICE]

[PROCESS]

[DRIVER]
srvnet SYSTEM
Legacy Kernel Caller SYSTEM
USB Audio Device SYSTEM
```

However, when I run `powercfg -requests` again, the output is the same as the first result and both drivers are still preventing my computer from sleeping. I restarted my computer and it's still the same. I set my computer to sleep after 1 minute of inactivity, but it will never sleep unless I manually sleep it via the start menu.

I'm willing to post any other details/logs if needed. Just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Have you restarted since making the changes?

Comment: Did you make the changes running as Administrator?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes and yes. I'll update my question with those details. Thanks.

Comment: @hobbes3 did you ever figure this out.  I'm seeing the exact same things.   I know that program that is triggering the drivers, so i can shut it down and the computer sleeps normally,  but when it's running the overrides aren't respected and the system stays awake

Comment: Same here, nothing works, device keeps system alive

Answer (score 0):

Same here but only with Legacy Kernel Caller. No clue whats using that driver. Overriding won't work too. @Eric L you posted that you've managed to find what program is triggering it. Can you share what it was in your case?

Edit:

Someone, elsewhere, posted a solution that in his case overriding worked by calling it by full path listed in brackets in /requests output. In this case requestsoverride would look like:

```
Powercfg -requestsoverride Driver "USB\VID_1395&PID_005E&MI_00\6&61162f7&0&0000" System
```

I haven't tested it but all in all in my case it was Rainmeter audio output visualizer on the desktop which was causing constant Legacy Kernel Caller wake request. Even when no audio playback was present. I found it by disconnecting my external USB SoundBlaster sound card. Than Legacy Kernel Caller disappeared and NVIDIA High Definition Audio (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10DE&DEV_0092&SUBSYS_14584008&REV_1001\5&2094fbe8&0&0001) appeared. Because the audio output and driver changed. After this I narrowed it down to Rainmeter VisBubble Skin.